# Typed default exports in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, export

I tried searching for this but couldnt find it.  I'm trying to do this

```
import { Variables } from './types';


export default: Variables = {
  type: 'set_variables',
  variables: {
    show_cursor: false,
    win_size: 400,
    is_text_only: false,
    type_time: 0.05,
  },
};
```

getting syntax errors.  Do I have to first set it as a variable and then export the variable as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in this way -

```
import { Variables } from './types';

const variable: Variables = {
    type: 'set_variables',
    variables: {
        show_cursor: false,
        win_size: 400,
        is_text_only: false,
        type_time: 0.05,
    },
};

export default variable;
```

Or

```
import { Variables } from './types';

export default {
    type: 'set_variables',
    variables: {
        show_cursor: false,
        win_size: 400,
        is_text_only: false,
        type_time: 0.05,
    },
} as Variables;
```